# Passing phone input via Twilio

Tags: java, http, twilio, twilio-twiml, spark-framework

I'm working on a basic Twilio web application using Java and the Spark Java framework. I'm trying to have the user enter a number as input after the initial prompt through a Gather verb and then process that input. So far, I am able to call my Twilio number and it responds with the initial prompt, but after I enter a number it goes to /handle-number and crashes because the request did not contain any params and it can't find the "Digits" param (params is empty when I print it).

I have tried to mimic the API call via the Postman Chrome extension to debug it, but I get a 500 internal server error.

EDIT: Here is a screenshot of the postman request : [Postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urpgN.png)

I am new to Java web applications, HTTP requests, and Twilio, so I am unfamiliar with much of this. I have gone thought the twiml documentation and tutorials and tried to follow along but my I'm definitely missing something in my implementation.

How do I properly pass the phone input to the processNumber Route? Any help is appreciated!

App.java

```
import static spark.Spark.*;

public class App {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        post("/receive-call", ReceiveCall.call);
        post("/handle-number", ReceiveCall.processNumber);
    }
}
```

ReceiveCall.java

```
import com.twilio.twiml.voice.Gather;
import com.twilio.twiml.voice.Say;
import com.twilio.twiml.*;
import spark.Route;

public class ReceiveCall {

    public static Route call = (request, response) -> {    
        Say sayMessage = new Say.Builder("Hello! Please enter a number as input. Enter # when finished.").build();
        Gather input = new Gather.Builder().timeout(3).say(sayMessage).action("/handle-number").build();
        VoiceResponse twiml = new VoiceResponse.Builder().gather(input).build();

        System.out.println(response.body());

        return twiml.toXml();
        };

    public static Route processNumber = ((request, response) -> {    
        String digit = request.params("Digits");

        //CRASHES HERE BECAUSE digit IS NULL
        int number = Integer.parseInt(digit);

        Say message = process(number);
        VoiceResponse twiml = new VoiceResponse.Builder().say(message).build();
        return twiml.toXml();
    });
```

Comment: Can you provide the screenshot of your Postman API call? Especially on how the `Digits` parameter is sent.

Comment: I added a screenshot link. I tried sending the Digits parameter as a URL parameter and as part of the body, but both result in the same error.

Comment: What is the `Content-Type` of your POST request?

Comment: `request.params()` is for path params, such as: "/handle-number/:Digits". What you need is `request.queryParams()`, which is for "/handle-number?Digits=..."

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it! In what scenario would I receive data through `request.params()`? I'm not entirely sure what a path parameter is.

Comment: you are welcome, please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of "digit IS NULL" is: you are using `request.params(...)`, which is for path parameter.

**What is "path parameter"?**

"path parameter" means passing parameter as part of URL path, especially in RESTful style request.

For example, if you want to send an HTTP GET request to retrieve a book by its ISBN, the request URL could be: `/books/9787121022982` or `/books/9787101054491`, where the ISBN parameter is passed as part of URL path (`9787121022982` and `9787101054491`). In Spark framework, the corresponding Route code would be:

```
get("/books/:isbn", (request, response) -> {
    return "Book ISBN is: " + request.params(":isbn");
});
```

**What is "query parameter"?**

"query parameter" means passing parameter as part of URL queries (entities after the `?` character in URL).

Take the previous book ISBN case for example, if you want to pass ISBN as query parameter, the HTTP GET URL would be: `/books?isbn=9787121022982`, and the corresponding Spark Route code is:

```
get("/books", (request, response) -> {
    return "Book ISBN is: " + request.queryParams("isbn");
});
```

**What is the best practice to pass data in POST request?**

In your case, the `/handle-number` route accept POST request. For HTTP POST request, it's not a good practice to pass data as parameter in URL. Instead, you need to pass data as request body, and get data from body in Spark code:

```
post("/handle-number", (request, response) -> {
    String body = request.body();
    // extract ISBN from request body string
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is parsing through `request.body()` the only way to get the POST request information? Or can I do something like `request.params(":Digits")` if I change the POST route to `post("/handle-number/:Digits", ReceiveCall.processNumber);`

Comment: you are mixing 2 separate things,  
you can use request.queryParams("Digits") for both POST and GET requests.
The ":" character is just a shorthand in the sparkjava framework for allowing you to access part of the url 
see http://sparkjava.com/documentation#routes
So in answer to your question , no you do not need request.body to get information over a POST

Comment: Yes, you can use `request.queryParams("Digits")` in both POST and GET, but it's not a good practice to send data through URL in POST :)